# prepareStatement arroja null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta pero no se realizaba correctamente, debugeando encontre que una vez que se llega al objeto ps de tipo PreparedStatement, se salta al catch(marcando un error de tipo null), es como si la consulta que estoy pasandole arriba(sql) no le pasara nada, no entiendo, estoy desde 4 horas en este, por favor comunidad ayudenme a resolver este problema con su inmensa sabiduria

Ya valide que el objeto user y dni esten correcto, tambien que la conexion con la base de datos es correcta.

```
public class EmployeeDAO {
    Conection cn = new Conection();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    
    public Employee Validate(String user, String dni){
        Employee em= new Employee();
        String sql="select * from empleado where User = ? and Dni= ?";
        
        System.out.println(sql);
            
        try{
            con=cn.Conection();
          
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);            
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ps.setString(2, dni);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                em.setId(rs.getInt("IdEmpleado"));
                em.setUser(rs.getString("User"));
                em.setDni(rs.getString("Dni"));
                em.setNom(rs.getString("Nombres"));

            }

         } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e);
         }
    
    return em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en la parte de conexion despues de realizada, le asignaba nuevamente de valor a la variable que llevaba la conexion el valor de null, cierro mi pregunta.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).